# Persistant login during django selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, django-testing

Here the snippet I'm using for my end-to-end tests using selenium (i'm totally new in selenium django testing) ;

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

class MyTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(DashboardTest, cls).setUpClass()

        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        cls.user = User.objects.create_superuser(username=...,
                                                 password=...,
                                                 email=...)
        time.sleep(1)
        cls._login()

    @classmethod
    def _login(cls):
        cls.selenium.get(
            '%s%s' % (cls.live_server_url, '/admin/login/?next=/'))
        ...

    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.assertIn(self.username,
                      self.selenium.find_element_by_class_name("fixtop").text)

    def test_go_to_dashboard(self):
        query_json, saved_entry = self._create_entry()
        self.selenium.get(
            '%s%s' % (
                self.live_server_url, '/dashboard/%d/' % saved_entry.id))
        # assert on displayed values

    def self._create_entry():
        # create an entry using form  and returns it

    def test_create(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        query_json, saved_entry = self._create_entry()
        ... assert on displayed values
```

I'm noticed that between each test the login is not persistant. So i can use `_login` in the `setUp` but make my tests slower.

So how to keep persistant login between test ? What are the best practices for testing those tests  (djnago selenium tests) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kevinharvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814007/kevinharvey) pointed me to the solution! Finally found out a way to reduce time of testing and keeping track of all tests:

I have renamed all methods starting with `test..` to `_test_..` and added a main method that calls each `_test_` method:

```
def test_main(self):
    for attr in dir(self):
        # call each test and avoid recursive call
        if attr.startswith('_test_') and attr != self.test_main.__name__:
            with self.subTest("subtest %s " % attr):
                self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url)
                getattr(self, attr)()
```

This way, I can test (debug) individually each method :)

Answer (score 1):

Through-the-browser tests with Selenium are slow, period. They are, however, very valuable as they're the best shot you have at automating the true user experience.

You shouldn't try to write true unit tests with Selenium. Instead, use it to write one or two large functional tests. Try to capture an entire user interaction from start to finish. Then structure your test suite so that you can run your fast, non-Selenium unit tests separately, and only have to run the slow functional tests on occasion.

Your code looks fine, but in this scenario you'd combine `test_go_to_dashboard` and `test_create` into one method.

Comment: Thanks :) I split the tests against the main application functionalities and because if I use a large test; it will be exit after the first failure and i will not be able to test the rest of my scenario.

Comment: Right. This is why Selenium tests are brittle, but I'd still say the right way to do it is write a single function that has a lot of repeated action-assertion-action-assertion. If you want quick feedback on targeted functionality, write unit test WITHOUT Selenium.

Here's an example that I use alot: https://github.com/kevinharvey/jmad/blob/test-driven-django-development/jmad/jmad/tests.py#L47